# How can I shorten this if/elif python code?

Tags: python

I have this if code for a vending machine and I feel like it could be shortened, any ideas?

```
Potato_size = raw_input(“Would you like a small, medium or large potato?”)
if Potato_size == “Small”:
    print “The price is £1.50 without toppings, continue?”
elif Potato_size == “Medium”:
    print “The price is £2.00 without toppings, continue?”
elif Potato_size == “Large”:
    print “The price is £2.50 without toppings, continue?”
else:
    print “Please answer Small, Medium or Large.”
```

Thanks

Comment: Better use [proper quotes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=quotes#string-and-bytes-literals)

Answer (score 6):

That should remove the `if/elif` clauses

```
Potato_size = raw_input("Would you like a small, medium or large potato?")

Sizes={"Small":"£1.50","Medium":"£2.00","Large":"£2.50"}
try:
   print "The price is {} without toppings, continue?".format(Sizes[str(Potato_size)])
except NameError:
    print "Please answer Small, Medium or Large."
```

Comment: Yes! This is THE way to go

Comment: You really should have `except NameError:` instead of the blanket except

Comment: or use Sizes.get(str(Potato_size,'This is not on sale'))

Answer (score 0):

Not the best but it's the shortest posted yet.

```
sizes={"SMALL":"£1.50","MEDIUM":"£2.00","LARGE":"£2.50"}
price_str = {k: "The price is {} without toppings, continue?".format(v)
                 for k, v in sizes.iteritems()}

potato_size = raw_input("Would you like a small, medium or large potato?  ")
print price_str.get(potato_size.upper(), "Please answer Small, Medium or Large.\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a dict to shorten this,

```
potato_size ={
    "small": “The price is £1.50 without toppings, continue?”
    "medium":“The price is £2.00 without toppings, continue?”
    "large" :“The price is £2.50 without toppings, continue?”
}
user_input =  raw_input(“Would you like a small, medium or large potato?”)
if user_input in potato_size :
    print potato_size[user_input]
else:
    print “Please answer Small, Medium or Large.”
```

Comment: Hard-coding the whole statement to print in the dictionary is not a flexible solution.